# Anyway to retrieve a feed of posts that have BOTH tags?

Tags: tags, feed

If I use the URL "/tag/tag1,tag2/feed", it will retrieve posts that have both tags. Is there anyway to do this and just get posts that have BOTH tag1 and tag2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a custom rss feed.....

Here's a link for that 
http://yoast.com/custom-rss-feeds-wordpress/

Simply use that info to make a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)

Make a new page through the WP interface and assign that template

The url for that page is your new feed.

You just need to [adjust the query line](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) to call to both tags

For instance, I have a hockey feed, my custom post type is col_avs, I've adjusted my query like:

```
$posts = query_posts('post_type=col_avs&showposts='.$numposts);
```

You can see it in action at http://www.rvoodoo.com/hockey-feed
It goes to a feedburner feed, but that feed is generated using this method

Answer (score 0):

Im not to sure if you can or can not do this. I usually just merge the two with Yahoo pipes since i use feedburner for most of my feeds check it out http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/